# NodeJS Type buffer inconsistency

Tags: node.js, image, express, mongoose, buffer

I have a question about Buffer Type. I'm new in NodeJs and I need help to understand how Buffer Type work. Lets to example:

I have a field "picture" in my Schema "User".

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  picture: { type: Buffer, contentType: String}
});
```

Also, I have an endpoint to get the informations. It is pretty simple:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, u) {            
  res.send(u);
});
```

There is no problem at this point. 
But I'm facing for an inconsistency in this response.

**Case 01 (res.send(u)):** 
    When I have all my document in my response the Buffer field is something like that:

```
{ 
  "name": "aaa", 
  "picture": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [100,97,116,97,58,105,...]
  }
}
```

**Case 02 (res.send(u.picture)):** 
When I have only the picture field, my response is something like that:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAADAFBMVEUODAkjCgYbGBQTJwZFEBIuHBZjDw8ZLkUyKCNFJRonOA1cIglNLBYgN1QiQCSDExlWJi+pAw4+NDJrICxkKg8zRBNKOCFbMSo1RDrEAxRvLxFVOiNnMh6ZGCEpRWo8TB5fPRF1MhOELQpMQEBBUA1BQVxfOjJ6KUpZQighV088TEF6NhdYQT1qPCvDFCFFVSO1GyhLTzeKK06COhkrWGdEU0hZSkYhY1pBT3NuShdiSEGaLjh8QCxBWz0XaWYRX61wSDAwbRxNXCzrDCpVVzZBYy6LQR62KDFqR1ufOxBTV0hiT0tySj9LXFFbVFc3XYyZNV1IWYBXZxKFSjZpVk3FLDiWSSR7VjFmWlZUajdhYU...
```

My question is: why is that occur and how I make to have a response like below?

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "picture: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAADAFBMVEUODAkjCgYbGBQTJwZFEBIuHBZjDw8ZLkUyKCNFJRonOA1cIglNLBYgN1QiQCSDExlWJi+pAw4+NDJrICxkKg8zRBNKOCFbMSo1RDrEAxRvLxFVOiNnMh6ZGCEpRWo8TB5fPRF1MhOELQpMQEBBUA1BQVxfOjJ6KUpZQighV088TEF6NhdYQT1qPCvDFCFFVSO1GyhLTzeKK06COhkrWGdEU0hZSkYhY1pBT3NuShdiSEGaLjh8QCxBWz0XaWYRX61wSDAwbRxNXCzrDCpVVzZBYy6LQR62KDFqR1ufOxBTV0hiT0tySj9LXFFbVFc3XYyZNV1IWYBXZxKFSjZpVk3FLDiWSSR7VjFmWlZUajdhYU..."
}
```

**Details: I'm using mongoose with express.**

Answer (score 0):

When you use the whole object what you see is a `Buffer` object type, with some binary data representation.

But when you use `u.picture` node is trying to convert the buffer to string by calling `u.picture.toString()` which results in the representation of what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandruOlaru for the clean answer. But how I have both at the same time?
I want name and picture.toString() at the same response

Comment: Unfortunately it is not work. I even tried this: u.picture = new Buffer(u.picture, 'base64').toString('binary') without success

Comment: Just work if I build a new Json like: 
newJson.user = u;
newJson.picture = u.picture

Comment: @brunnogrillo glad to help

Comment: Yes, but it is not the solution I want. Because what happens when I have many users in the response? I have to do a loop? It is not seems right